# How to Authenticate/Complete sign-in for Firebase user on a web page

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an Angular application and I'm using Firebase Authentication for authentication, everything works fine but now I want to move the email confirmation/verification into my web-app and not using the default firebase verification.

So far, I have updated the Email address verification template in firebase as per this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)

I have also created an Angular component with the correct route URL and I am redirected to the correct page once clicked on the verification link.
I can also confirm that the url parameters contain the correct apiKey for my app as well as the oobCode and that the correct data is passed into the service.
This is the url:
http://localhost:4200/account/verify?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=IddWYommjn4Y9ASiaOFHD6JjKypZnb_0_0hyAfRNjw0AAAGIBwHSWg&apiKey=AIzaSyDBVHE2J7-yl7DWwEI7YEe5ZmfV4U&lang=en

Errors I am getting:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used. (auth/invalid-action-code).
>
> {message: "INVALID_OOB_CODE", domain: "global", reason: "invalid"}

My implementation is as follows:

authentication.service.ts:

```
  import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
  import { signInWithEmailLink } from "firebase/auth";

  VerifyEmail(email: string, query: string) {
    console.log(email, query);
    return signInWithEmailLink(getAuth(), email, query);
  }
```

verify-email.component.ts

```
  public verifyEmail(email: string) {
    if (this.paramQuery) {
      this.authService.VerifyEmail(email, window.location.href)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('result', result)
        if (result.user) {
          this.userService.setSessionUser(result.user);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
  }
```